# Find the count for 2 values for single customer

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTOnB.png)

How can I find the count of number of connects and disco for each complex id in here

I have tried to use the case statement but getting the wrong count for connect and disco

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 A.COMPLEX_ID
,A.PAYROLL_DATE
,A.STRATEGIC_PRODUCT
,CASE WHEN A.NATURE_OF_CHANGE_CD = 'CONNECT' THEN COUNT(A.COMPLEX_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPLEX_ID)  ELSE 0 END C1
,CASE WHEN A.NATURE_OF_CHANGE_CD = 'DISCO' THEN COUNT(A.COMPLEX_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPLEX_ID)  ELSE 0 END C1
```

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the conditional inside the aggregate. Also, drop the `ELSE 0`, because `0` is countable just like `A.COMPLEX_ID`. The default for `ELSE` is `NULL`, which does not get counted.

You can also replace `A.COMPLEX_ID` with any non-null value. I typically use the constant `1` when doing conditional counts.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.COMPLEX_ID
    ,A.PAYROLL_DATE
    ,A.STRATEGIC_PRODUCT
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NATURE_OF_CHANGE_CD = 'CONNECT' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPLEX_ID) C1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NATURE_OF_CHANGE_CD = 'DISCO' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COMPLEX_ID) C1
```